# JNI XOR Encryption Eclipse build error

Tags: android, c, eclipse, encryption, java-native-interface

I want to XOR operator for byte or char array using JNI. I make native method using byte or char array and key which I have to use for encryption or decryption. For single line of XOR I amn't able to build C file in eclipse becasue of "void value not ignored as it ought to be". 
I added `jchar *xor` for solve void error than I get one more error "invalid use of void expression"
I amn't able to solve this. here is my code for c.

```
int
Java_packagename_classname_encryption(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj,
         jcharArray buffer,  jint offset,
         jint length,  jcharArray _key,  jint keylength){


        jint temp,i ;
        jint _keyByteIndex = 0;
        jcharArray xor[length]  ;


        for(i=0; i<length + offset; ++i){

            /*char temp = buffer[i];
            temp ^= _key[_keyByteIndex];
            buffer[i] = (char) temp;*/

            buffer[i] = (jchar) (buffer[i] ^ _key[_keyByteIndex]);

            if (_keyByteIndex + 1 >=keylength){
                _keyByteIndex = 0;
            }else{
                ++_keyByteIndex;
            }

        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `jcharArray` is not an array that you can access directly with `[]`. It's a `jobject`, and to access the actual array data you need to use the appropriate [JNI functions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html).

Comment: @Michael thanks but can you please write single line code for me so i can understand. i study jni.h but cant able to understand perfect syntax.

Comment: Any one have idea how to catch exception in JNI C Native code i tried with simple try catch but gives many errors like ::   - 'try' undeclared (first use in this function)
 - each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears 
  in
 - expected ';' before '{' token
 - Statement has no effect 'try'
 - Symbol 'try' could not be resolved
 - Missing ';'

Comment: C doesn't have exceptions. You you mean that you want to catch Java exceptions in your C code then you should look up `ExceptionCheck` and `ExceptionClear` on the page I linked to in my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jcharArray` is a typedef for `jarray`, which is a typedef for `jobject` which is a typedef for `void*`. It could be anything, it could be a unicorn disguised as a void pointer.

You can't use dereference it with `_key[_keyByteIndex]`. You have to use `(*env)->GetCharArrayElements`, which will return what you want: `jchar*`.

I suggest you to look at the `jni.h` you're using, it should give you all the answers you need.

Comment: Thanks for reply,Please explain me in detail i tried with both. I dont have more exp.xor[i] = (*env)->GetCharArrayElements(env,buffer[i] ^  _key[_keyByteIndex]);
          //xor[i] = (*env)->GetCharArrayElements(env,buffer[i])   ^  (*env)->GetCharArrayElements(env,_key[_keyByteIndex]);      Error: "Method 'GetCharArrayElements' could not be resolved"

Comment: Check the `jni.h` you're using for the correct method signature.